# My site thinks it's secure when it is fact not

Tags: security, ssl, https

My site is loading enqueued content over HTTPS while it is not a secure site.

I have a couple PHP sites behind a load balancer with a proxy ssl certificate on one other domain. This site does not have a certificate.

When I output `is_secure` I get true, when I output `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` I get `'on'`.

[Here is a copy of my $_SERVER dump](https://gist.github.com/adampatterson/e73be701d3c788ab32d6b7387503f527).

No other sites are having this issue.

I attempted to use `force_ssl_content(false)` in my functions.php but didn't have any luck; in fact it just broke the site. Didn't see any examples of how to avoid setting SSL, only how to force SSL.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

wp_config was set up to force SSL by overwriting $_SERVER['HTTPS'], I respolved the issue.

I assume someone was trying to make SSL work behind the proxy at one point.

It would actually be a much better solution ( specifically for asset links ) to use the double slash //